# User keeps editing questions incorrectly

Tags: discussion, editing

There 's [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/64266/david-marm-ansermot) user that goes around any question he can find and edits it. What the issue is, his edits add exactly zero value to the question. Most of the edits are few new lines, where he sees fit, removing simple "thank you" from the OP etc, its hardly if ever any spelling mistakes fixed. All his badges are edits, upvotes and such. He can just as easily be 101 rep.

Is the only course of action rejecting his edits, as I'm 99% sure he won't get the memo any time soon ?

Comment: Side note: some of his edits were technically proper, but not something I'd bother dredging up questions that were 2+ years old for (although many of those often added a weird space before punctuation).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This user has already been automatically banned from editing by the system for submitting too many bad edits.

Comment: So he will get the memo sooner rather than later. Thanks for the information!

Comment: I flagged this user a while ago for overall useless edits, and my flag was declined. Oh well, seems like he was banned anyway....